# Count files in ZIP's directory - JAVA, Android

Tags: java, android, file, count, zip

I have a little irritating problem. How can I count files in directory in Zip? I want to avoid use `ZipFile.entries()` and then test every enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count all files use `ZipFile.size()`.

To count files in a specific directory the method you describe is the only option. Zip files are stored not with a hierarchical structure, just as a flat list with the file paths given.

It also varies as to whether these paths are absolute (for the source file system) or relative.

Comment: I want only count files in specify directory not all zip file.

Answer (score 0):

For count file on particular directory use below code.

```
int Sdcardcount = 0;
 File fileCount = new File(dirPath);
             File[] list = fileCount.listFiles();
             for (File f : list) {
             String name = f.getName();
             if (name.endsWith(".zip"))
             Sdcardcount++;
             }
```